# Where to find ServerName in a PHP Script

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.2, configuration

I'm looking to retrieve the `ServerName` field located in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. My only issue is then calling it in PHP (`echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`) it gives me not the server name but the ip address.

If I pull a `phpinfo();` I can the server name under the `Hostname:Port` field under the apache2handler, so I know it's accessible somehow.

Comment: If you can not find it in $_SERVER['HTTP_SERVER_NAME'] perhaps consider that your Apache2/PHP configuration is not 'right'.

Comment: But it shows up in `phpinfo()`, it can be found there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP do a

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

or even

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Should help you. I have a feeling it is probably $_SERVER['HTTP_SERVER_NAME'] but do the above and it will tell you exactly

Comment: It's not in $_SERVER at all, I'll check $_REQUEST.

Comment: Nope, nothing there either. This is similar to [this other question I found](http://serverfault.com/questions/44786/anyway-for-php-to-retrive-hostnameport-from-apache2handler) but the answer is unclear.

Comment: And you can't use HTTP_HOST?

Comment: In your phpinfo() output scroll downto "Apache Environment" section,  is there anything in there?

Comment: Yeah, fixed it. Had something to do with `UseConicalName` or something.

Comment: So why'd you give the answer to me? You can answer yourself, so that way the person that comes along next will see your answer...